# Java synchronized methods/monitors, if a method acquires the lock, does it keep it until the method ends?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, monitor

I'll try to be as short as possible. I'm studying monitors at university and we described a model to implement it through semaphores. The way we modeled it if a thread entered a method `f` from a monitor, the thread would either complete the method, suspend itself to `wait` for a condition or suspend itself cause it woke up another method waiting for a condition (namely, `notify` or `notifyAll` equivalents in Java).

I tried solving problems with monitor/synchronized methods in Java and more than once I had the impression that a thread could be removed at any point during the execution of a synchronized method allowing other methods to enter as well. Specifically, on some methods I have code snippets like this:

```
while( /* some condition */ ) 
  wait();
```

Where "some condition" would be something like calling a second synchronized method to test if some list satisfies conditions that can't be checked in O(1), like if the maximum of the list is smaller than some threshold. And the thing is, some times I get exceptions that would make no sense.

To be more concrete, once I had to solve a problem where I had an `HashMap` holding a list for each key, and "producer" threads would add a new number to their list (each producer has its own unique list) and another thread would wait for all the producers to write their data and then return the sum. Code looking something like this:

```
public synchronized int consume() throws InterruptedException {
   if( !isDataReady() )
      wait();
   
   int sum = 0;
   for( UUID producer : theHashMap.keySet() ) 
      sum += theHasMap.get( producer ).get(p);
   
   p++;
   notifyAll();
   return sum;
}
 
public synchronized boolean isDataReady() {
   if( theHashMap.keySet().size() <= 0 )
      return false;
  else {
      boolean dataReady = true;
      for( UUID prod : theHashMap.keySet() ) 
        if( !dataReady )
          return false;
        else
          dataReady = dataReady && theHashMap.get(prod).size() >= (p+1);
       
      return dataReady; 
  }
```

And the `consume()` method often gave me `IndexOutOfBoundsException` for trying to access position `p` with the arraylist being of size `p`. I can't understand if it's because of some race condition happening that causes the condition to falsely test as true or what.

Comment: Is it a typo that you write `if (!isDataReady())` instead of `while (!isDataReady())`? Just because someone calls `notify()` or `notifyAll()` doesn't mean that data is suddenly ready, so you probably need to check that again.

Comment: Calling `wait` releases the monitor (the lock) while the thread is sleeping, and reacquires it when woken up again by a `notify`.

Comment: @Hoopje: you're completely correct. In fact my original code has while instead of if in it. I typed the one in my question on the fly just to have an example where I struggled with the problem I'm facing. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @passer-by: Sorry for the question, might sound stupid but I can't find the answer: can two different threads be active at the same time inside two different methods of the same monitor? Like on two different cores of the CPU? Basing on the model we saw at university I'd say no but we didn't discuss the java implementation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. That's the point - to establish a critical region that admits only one thread of execution at a time.  (Nit with Java terminology - the monitor is not the entire object, it's the parts that implement 'synchronized' for that object, so 'methods of the monitor' is odd-sounding. This differs from classical Hoare terminology)

Comment: But note this only applies to synchronized methods and synchronized blocks that synchronize on the same object.  There's no magic to stall methods that don't synchronize.

Comment: @passer-by: So if I understood correctly, two different threads can be active at the same time inside two different synchronized methods of a same object, is that correct?

Comment: Not if they're synchronized on the same object.  The monitor has a one-to-one correspondence with the object.  [ref: JLS 17.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.1)

Comment: @passer-by: So if I have a class that contains `public synchronized void foo() {...}` and `public synchronized void bar() {...}` and I instantiate an object of that class, it cannot happen that two distinct threads are active respectively in `foo()` and `bar()` of the same instance (as it sounds the most reasonable to me)

Comment: Correct, but depending on what you mean by 'active'.  If a thread is waiting inside a call to `wait` it no longer owns the monitor, but is still 'inside' foo or bar.

Comment: @passer-by: With "active" I mean in "execution" state. I appreciate your effort to help me, thank you!